# Define a custom <a> tag in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In my website, I need two types of `<a>` tags -- one for inline links and the other for standalone links. So you can imagine I want these two types of `<a>` tags to be in different colors/styles.

For example, for inline links, I don't want to make them pop out too much, so I want light underlines beneath them. On the contrary, I want standalone links to pop out, so I want to color them in bright blue.

My idea is to create two tags, `<a_inline>` and `<a>`. How may I do this? I tried making a copy of `<a>`, renamed the copy to `<a_inline>`, and modified the color attribute, etc., but the thing is not clickable.

Comment: Why not use [classes](https://jsfiddle.net/k3zp0x3v/)?

Comment: Yes  use classes .. this is tipical case ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create your own elements, if you do that then you aren't using HTML any longer. ([Custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) are a thing, but not appropriate here).

In general, the two tools for grouping elements together are:

- [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) + [Class selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html)
- An ancestor element combined with a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)

Using classes would look something like:

```css
a {
  color: red;
}
a.inline {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">External link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#foo" class="inline">Inline link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

While the other approach would be:

```css
a {
  color: red;
}
article a {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">External link</a>

<article>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. <a href="#foo">Inline link</a>. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce
    nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero.</p>


</article>
```

In this particular case, however, you already have enough distinguishing features in the HTML to not need to add anything.

Assuming I understand you correctly, your inline links will have `href` attributes with values starting with the `#` symbol. You can use that in an [attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors):

```css
a {
  color: red;
}
a[href^="#"] {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">External link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#foo">Inline link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! For the first approach, how do I add `:hover` settings to the new `a.inline`? Right now, it seems to have inherited everything from `a:hover`.

Comment: Actually, I don't even need to add `:hover` settings to the new `a.inline`. Just want to make `a.inline` have no `:hover` effects.

Comment: @SibbsGambling — You put `:hover` are the rest of the selector you want to modify

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `CSS classes`
Define two classes like this

```
a.one {
    // Custom style one
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a.two {
    // Custom style two
    color: cyan;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Then in your HTML code you can use both whenever you want.

```
<a class="one">One</a>
<a class="two">Two</a>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a CSS class. HTML has classes. CSS has class selectors.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create `<a-inline>`  (notice the `-`) you'll need JavaScript and [**document.registerElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement)

Otherwise you can do several things using **classes** or **attribute selectors** like:

```css
/* all anchors */
a{
  color:red;
}
/* .gold anchors */
a.gold{
  color:gold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/* ID fragment anchors */
a[href^='#']{
  color: blue;
}
/* Anchor href ends in .html */
a[href$='.html']{
  color: green;
}
/* Anchor is a http:// or https:// */
a[href^='http://'],
a[href^='https://']{
  color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<a>I don't have any href</a><br>
<a class="gold">I have a .gold</a><br>
<a href="#something">I'm an ID anchor</a><br>
<a href="./somepage.html">This is a .html link</a><br>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">This is a http link</a><br>
```